# Is there an API to create albums and upload photos to Pages and groups?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

In our APP we are successfully creating albums and uploading photos to users accounts however there does not seem to be a way to create albums and upload photos to albums in Pages and groups.

Looks like we can publish photos to streams of pages and groups but not really manage albums.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can totally create create albums and post photos to Pages. There is a post on this here:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

To post to a page you just replace the user id with the page id, and make sure you have requested the publish_stream permission.

However, up until recently it seems that groups did not have albums and you could only publish a photo to the group timeline.

Groups now have albums, but it seems like you can't create them. When I try to I get a permissions error.  Has anyone else managed to create an album for a facebook group?

Comment: I also need this feature, but still haven't found a way to retrieve photos from group albums.